# Failed to copy Manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I downloaded a project from git through eclipse. When I try to run my project I would get this error:

> [2013-01-26 21:16:43 - FOLDERNAME] /FOLDERNAME/gen already exists but
>   is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.

After I delete the gen folder, I would get this error when I try to clean my project:

> [2013-01-26 21:23:38 - FOLDERNAME] Failed to copy Manifest

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you could check the permission of your fs... Maybe you could try to create a fake Manifest file... Maybe you could update your question to give us more information.

Answer (score 4):

The fix is:
**Clean the project** by going to *Project > Clean*.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path
2. Open the Source tab
3. Click on "Add Folder..." and select BOTH gen and src

If you are still having issues after that:

1. Right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path
2. Select the Libraries tab
3. Click the "Add External JARs..." button. Select the API that is in your android directory (android-sdk\platforms\android-yourversion)

Make sure to Clean the project afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Go to /bin folder and delete AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: please provide a bit more information (perhaps why this is the solution)

Answer (score 1):

Go manifest.xml location and press right click on manifest.xml, select properties and uncheck read only property.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is to

- right-click the project node in Eclipse
- select the Android tools submenu
- select Fix project properties

You may need to close and reopen the project but after this, it should build properly.

The reason for this is that .classpath and .project files are often by default ignored in .gitignore, and these settings are then missing when fetching the project from git.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Failed to copy Manifest error when I loaded the project and here is what got the project running:

- in the Problems tab, click the error message
- delete it (by hitting the delete key on your keyboard, I'm serious)
- r-click the main project node in Package Explorer/ Run As Android Application